# Excel lookup() always returns last value

Tags: microsoft-excel, lookup

I am using Excel on a larger table (3148 col) and I am doing a lookup. 
I've tried it with just 10 columns and it worked as expected but when I do my lookup with all the entries it just fails by always returning the last value.

For example my table looks like this

```
+-------+--------+----------------+
| Name  | Salary | RandomUniqueId |
+-------+--------+----------------+
| Peter |   1234 |           4242 |
| Kathy |   3312 |           4221 |
| Jonas |   2474 |           1238 |
+-------+--------+----------------+
```

My function:
=LOOKUP(4221;C2:C4;A2;A4)

Comment: `=lookup()` requires the data in the lookup column to be sorted ascending.   In your example, the opposite is true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in a comment to your question, the Lookup() function requires the data to be sorted. If you cannot sort the data, you can use an Index/Match combination, which works with unsorted data, too.

=Index(A:A,match(4221,C:C,0))

The 0 in the Match function means that the data can be unsorted and only an exact match is returned.